# Bootstrap 3 - the menu occupies the entire screen when on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot figure out what I have done wrong...

What I am trying to do is make the Twitter Bootstrap menu behave correctly.

The problem I am experiencing is that on a mobile the menu can collapse and retract but it covers the entire mobile, i.e. you cant see the rest of the page below.

I have literally copied and pasted a bootstrap 3 example and that doesn't work when I host it!!! Have I missed something very obvious? This is probably best viewed on a mobile....

Here is the page that I put my code on http://www.hackerhotshots.com/y.php

And the original page here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Can anyone pls see what I am doing so wrong?

Thanks -

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your example. It's working fine for me on my computer.

Comment: That's the thing - it works fine on a regular computer - its a mobile screen that refuses to show anything below the menu....

(thanks for looking!)

Comment: Just looked on a mobile device - both your site and the bootstrap example site look identical.

Comment: even when you collapse the menu can you scroll down the page?

If so then I must be going crazy - my android dolphin and android firefox both show that I cant scroll past the menu on my site....

Comment: Tested on iOS 5.1.1 - Works perfectly.
Tested on Android 4.4 w/Mozilla Aurora - Works perfectly.